# Image manually slide by mouse button

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two image. Say image A and B. I want to display image A and B 50% 50% in one div. Now user can slide that image to see other full (100%) image. Like want to see B slide A left side. How to do it? I have no any idea. I want to do it with html, jquery,css.

[image]

by click on red circle and drag it to the left side user can see the full image of image B. And same for A drag red circle to right user can see full image of image A.

Comment: So you want to have 3 images, two in one div and another one outside of it? Or in the same div?

Comment: no sir i have only 2 image. both image should be in one div.

Comment: So you want to do some sort of carousel ? If not I suggest either to draw some schema of what you want or explain a little more (maybe add some of your html code)

Comment: This link might help you. You need to modify some code. [Moving image in canvas with mouse](http://jsfiddle.net/rVx5G/12/)

Comment: i edited my que. plz give code and suggestion.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcdh4r07/)

Comment: yes but i want to drag an image.

Comment: means by drag middle black border.

Comment: @DeepParekh Check out a second solution, even simplier, that I've added to my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qerf1gdz/6/)**

In this markup, the first image is behind the second one. The second image is the one that slides left/right.

```
<div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/180/nature">
    <aside>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/180/people">
    </aside>
</div>
```

jQuery where we track the mouse dragging on the parent `div` container:

```
var $container = $('div'), // you should use a more specific selector, not just `div`
    $aside = $('aside', $container),
    parentX = $container.position().left,
    onMouseMove = function(e) {
        var left = e.clientX - parentX;
        $aside.css('left', left).children('img').css('left', -left);        
    };

$('img', $container).on('dragstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // disable dragging img
});

$container.mousedown(function() {
    $container.on("mousemove", onMouseMove);
}).mouseup(function() {
    $container.off("mousemove", onMouseMove);
});
```

and finally the css:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: ew-resize;
}

div img, div aside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div aside {
    left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: -5px 0 0 red;
}

div aside img {
    left: -100%;
}
```

---

### Solution 2

This one uses a simpler markup with only two images in a container.

```js
var $container = $('div'), // you should use a more specific selector, not just `div`
    $firstImg = $('img:first-child', $container),
    $secondImg = $('img:last-child', $container),
    parentX = $container.position().left;

$container.mousemove(function(e) {
    var x = e.clientX - parentX;
    $firstImg.css('clip', 'rect(0px, ' + x + 'px, 180px, 0px)');
    $secondImg.css('clip', 'rect(0px, 200px, 180px, ' + x + 'px)');
});
```

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 180px;
    cursor: ew-resize;
}

div img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

div img:first-child {
    clip: rect(0px, 100px, 180px, 0px);
}

div img:last-child {
    clip: rect(0px, 200px, 180px, 100px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/180/nature">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/180/people">
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the .off command. What is the Vanilla JS equivlant to unbind the mousemove event?

Comment: @magreenberg The jQuery `off()` does the same as the JS [removeEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)

Comment: Thanks. Learned something new.

Comment: @magreenberg You're welcome. Learning and sharing knowledge is what StackOverflow is all about.